# Identifying React component in reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

say I have a react component which takes in an id prop like so:

```
<Test id=3/>
```

In its corresponding reducer functions how can I identify which component I'm working with based on the id?

The test component also has some functions in its prop which are exported as a default if this affects anything.

Comment: `this.props.id`?

Comment: The reducer doesn't have a reference to 'this' unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Add the relevant code of the reducer

Comment: pass it to an action that updates the reducer? e.g.: `this.props.doSomething(this.props.id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducers doesn't and shouldn't know nothing about components.
They are pure functions that takes an action and return the next state.
For example, if we dispatched an action like this:
`{type: "ANSWER_UPVOTED", id: '123456'}`
Then we may have a reducer that handles this action:

```
const upvotesReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ANSWER_UPVOTED": {
            const currentAnswer = state.find(a => a.id == action.id);
            return {
                ...currentAnswer,
                votes: currentAnswer.numOfVotes + 1
            }
        }

        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Now if your component connected to `redux` it will have access to the new state.

Comment: so states are shared among all components which use the same reducer?

Comment: Not exactly, the `state` is global, each component that is connected to `redux` has access to the **entire** `state`. splitting reducers to handle a portion of the `state` is just makes it easier to maintain and scale, but you still have a single `redux` `state` (with the help of [combineReducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html))

Comment: oh right yes that makes sense. All the stuff I have done with combining reducers and stuff made me forget that really there's a single state behind it all. I think I can come up with a solution to my problem with your provided answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reducers are pure functions to change store and Observe changes to subscribers(Components). You can't and shouldn't work with components in reducers.

Comment: If you want pass some props to reducers, use action creators